# sharepoint 2007 webpart designer for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Is there a designer for SharePoint 2007 WebParts in Visual Studio?  I downloaded Visual Studio 2010, and see there is one for SharePoint 2010... but right now we are writing parts for 2007.  Alternatively, what is the overhead for using the ASP.NET developer, and porting the results to a SharePoint WebPart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use the same trick as VS 2010 does for SharePoint 2010.

In VS 2010, there is no real visual designer for Web parts, but a Web part is built out of a user control and of course VS has had a visual designer for user controls for a long time.

Look at [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309510.aspx). This article describes the code for a "Visual" Web part and includes the code that the Web part uses to load the user control (figure 5).

Comment: any idea why the ASP.NET user control template wouldn't be visible from a SharePoint Solution?

Comment: There is some info in a project item template to indicate to which project template it can be associated, but I could never figure it out, sorry. Creating an ASP.NET project alongside the SharePoint one, creating the user control there and moving the files to SharePoint should work, even if it is not elegant.